# Laravel 5 error querying group by with postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, heroku

I've got a problem with my Laravel 5 app. I'm deploying on Heroku server, and it works with Postgresql. On my local machine I've installed Mysql instead.

Everything works perfectly (on deploy I've chosen pgresql as database, and in local mysql), but there's a query which seems to make an error on Heroku.

Here's my query:

```
    $var = new Collection($obj->details()->groupBy('detail_id')->get(), new ObjWithDetailTransformer);
```

This query should only make a distinct before transforming the collection, grouping it by detail_id.

On my local machine works perfectly, but on my Heroku server it shows "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." message.

I don't know how to read logs, to see which is the error.

Thank you.

Comment: Enter `heroku logs --source app` as per the docs (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging) to filter your logs. Hit the page that runs the query and then check the logs and update your question.